# I do not understand this polarity symbol with 3 circles: positive, round, negative, and no lines

Tags: symbol, polarity

I am trying to figure out what is the right polarity of a power adapter for a small practice amplifier.

I know it is 9 VDC and I figured out the size of the plug and I know the wattage needed.

I do not understand what this polarity symbol with 3 circles (positive, round, negative, and no lines) on the amplifier means. I have included a picture of the connector and its symbol.

[image: Symbol in the DC Jack]

Thanks for your prompt help guys, now it is clear that the symbol is useless. Unfortunately I do not have an existing power adapter, the device also works with a 9V battery, that is what I am using now, but I really need the adapter.

Comment: Never saw anything like this before. Maybe it means that the polarity does not matter?

Comment: It looks to me like someone from Monkey Sea Enterprises didn't understand the importance of copying _everything exactly_ when they were doing something they didn't understand.  Your best bet if you have the old adaptor is to look at it.  If you don't, then do web searches to find a forum.  Somewhere down on the list is opening the thing up and looking at the circuit, or just trying it out with fingers crossed.

Comment: What Tim said. There is nothing in that symbol that can tell us anything about the polarity.  A current limited supply may be helpful during the trial.  Opening it up provides the best chance of success.

Comment: measure the resistance between battery terminals and the connector contacts

Comment: If you look at the [reviews on Amazon for that amp](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01JBLWBZU), they mention centre-negative, and there's also a link to an adaptor that someone used successfully which is wired centre-negative. But that's no help to decipher the symbols.

Comment: @jsotola and others have recommended measuring resistance between battery terminals and connector contacts. I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: I measured resistance and found Battery's Negative terminal is directly connected to Center contact in power adapter port. So it seems like it is a Center Negative adapter (thanks Andrew Morton). I may have one in my adapters box. Will give it a try and report back the results.

Answer (score 6):

There is no indication of polarity of that symbol. Either someone did not think that symbol through or there is no polarity. The best thing to do would be one of these things:

1. Contact the manufacturer
2. Find an equivalent power supply
3. Open it up and ohm it out. Find something with polarity like an electrolytic capacitor with a positive or negative terminal and see if it is directly connected ~0 Ohms to the positive or negative terminal.

Comment: Thanks @Voltage Spike, I will do step 1, contact the manufacturer. See what they recommend and post back here once I receive a reply.

Comment: Or use the internal battery as a guide to polarity. Which battery terminal is connected to which contact?

Answer (score 4):

Normally there is a horizontal line connecting the edge of either the + or - symbol to the center dot.  Without that, try this.

Measure the resistance between the phone connector to the left and each of the two power connector contacts.  If you are lucky, one of them will read less than 1 ohm.

No guarantees here, but this probably indicates which power connector contact is Ground, and that probably is the external 9 V source - output.

Comment: Now that we know it has a 9v battery connection, try this same test, checking for direct connection to one or both battery contacts.